# Trigger multiple POST requests in React child components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm working on a `React` app that lets the user setup some user objects to be created in some backend. After the user is done setting up the users to be created, a summary page is shown that shows the users that are about to be created in a table.

So when the user clicks an 'Export' button, I want to send a POST request to the backend for each user that is listed in the table. Each table row should show the current status of it's corresponding POST request. So my idea was to create a `Component` for the table rows and let each row handle it's POST request and response separately.

My problem is, how do I tell the child component to send the request? The button to trigger all requests is in the parent component.

As I understand it in `React` parent components are not supposed to call actions in child components. There seems to be a way to do that by using `React.forwardRef` and `React.useImperativeHandle` or something like that, but I that seems to be kind of complicated and makes me wondern if I'm on the right track for my usecase.

The only other idea I came up with was to use `useEffect` and a prop `sendTriggered` like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (sendTriggered) {
   sendPostRequest();
  }
}, [sendTriggered]);
```

The parent component would then set `sendTriggered` to `true` when the button is clicked. But that also seems to be abusing things^^

Of course I could also handle all requests and responses in the parent component and only hand the status down via `Props`, but I think each component should be responsible for it's own request.

Can anyone suggest a better approach? I would think that this is a rather common usecase.

Comment: Add more code to show what solution you've tried

Comment: I didn't try any solution yet. I'm sure I can come up with something that somehow works, but I'm looking more for some kind of best practice here or some advice of how to approach that problem from a design perspective.

Comment: You should have tried something before seeking help on stackoverflow